# Laravel I have an Error Undefined variable $ad when trying to do an edit

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to do an edit, I think the function is okay, but this error keeps showing

In edit view I have this, also, in routes, I have resource:

```
<form action="/user/{{$ad->id}}" method="POST" class="d-flex justify-content-center">
    <x-edit :ad="$ad">
        @csrf    
        @method('PUT')
    </x-edit>
</form>
```

In my edit component, here is where the $ad variable doesn't come, I tried using dd() and the error pops up, the route works because if I comment the form, and only keep the h1, it shows:

```
<div>
    <h1>Esto es el edit</h1>
    {{$slot}}
    <div class="formulario">
        <div class="mb-3 mt-3">
            <label class="label">Nombre del vendedor</label>
            <input class="form-control" id="ad_seller" name="ad_name" type="text" value='{{$ad->ad_seller}}'>
        </div>
        <div class="mb-3 mt-3">
            <label class="label">Nombre del producto</label>
            <input class="form-control" id="ad_name" name="ad_name" type="text" value='{{$ad->ad_name}}'>
        </div>
        <div class="mb-3 mt-3">
            <label class="label">Precio</label>
            <input class="form-control" id="ad_price" name="ad_price" type="number" value='{{$ad->ad_price}}'>
        </div>
        <div class="mb-3">
            <label class="label">Descripción</label>
            <input class="form-control" id="ad_description" name="ad_description" type="text" tabindex="3" value='{{$ad->ad_description}}'>
        </div>
        <div class="mb-3">
            <label class="label">Imagen</label>
            <input class="form-control" id="ad_image" name="ad_image" type="url" tabindex="4" value='{{$ad->ad_image}}'>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer d-flex">
            <button type="button" class="ml-3" data-bs-dismiss="modal"><a id="link_home" href="{{ route('home')}}">Cerrar</a></button>
            <button type="submit" tabindex="4">Guardar</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The function in controller Ad:

```
public function edit($id)
{
    $ad = Ad::find($id);
    return view('crud.edit')->with('ad', $ad);
}
```

Comment: This eror pops up syntax error, unexpected token "{" and I don't know where

Comment: There can be 2 -3 pointer due to which this error comes up. But before coming to conclusion, can you tell me where this error coming in blade or in controller ? Also where is the "{" unexpected token error coming ? please explain

Comment: Your heading seems to be quite different and you asked quite different thing in comment like unexpected "{". Please correct it what actually error coming

Answer (score 0):

I tried to recreate your issue on my local machine, and I think that the issue is when you try to pass the data to the blade component.

What you need to do is to edit the file `app/View/Components/Edit.php` and add two things:

1. add the property `public $ad = [];`
2. add the ad model as a parameter in the constructor, and then assign it to the property

Update it like this:

```
<?php

 namespace App\View\Components;

 use App\Models\Ad;
 use Illuminate\View\Component;

 class Edit extends Component
 {
  
      public $ad = [];
  
      /**
      * Create a new component instance.
      *
      * @return void
      */
      public function __construct(Ad $ad)
      {
          $this->ad = $ad;
      }

      /**
      * Get the view / contents that represent the component.
      *
      * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\View\View|\Closure|string
      */
      public function render()
      {
          return view('components.edit');
      }
 }
```

Comment: `Ad::find($id);` is literally shorthand for `Ad::where('id', $id)->first();`. The issue is that `$ad` is undefined in the view, not that it is `null`.

Comment: @TimLewis You're right, misunderstood the issue in the first place, edited my answer now that I clearly understood what the issue is. Hopefully, it will help the person who asked, and also thank you for pointing it out.

Answer (score 0):

Inside your form action, try to use the Laravel Blade Directive.

This action:

```
<form action="/user/{{$ad->id}}" method="POST" class="d-flex justify-content-center">
<x-edit :ad="$ad">
    @csrf    
    @method('PUT')
</x-edit>
```

Should be:

```
<form action="{{ route('user', $ad->id )}}" method="POST" class="d-flex justify-content-center">
<x-edit :ad="$ad">
    @csrf    
    @method('PUT')
</x-edit>
```